# How can I reformulate the following determinant?

Tags: matrices, determinant, inverse

I want to reformulate the following determinant:
$$ \left| \left(A^TB^{-1}A+ \frac{1}{c}C^{-1} \right)^{-1} \right|^{1/2} $$

where $c $ is a real scalar, $A$ is an ($n\times k$) matrix, $B$ is an ($n\times n$) matrix and C is a ($k\times k$) matrix. The dimension of matrix inside the above determinant is $k\times k$, so it is a square matrix.

By using the property of $\det(A^{-1})=\det(A)^{-1}$, the expression is written as

$$ \left|A^TB^{-1}A+ \frac{1}{c}C^{-1}  \right|^{-1/2} $$

How to reformulate this expression further?

I have read somewhere that it is equivalent to
$$ \left|  \frac{1}{c}C^{-1} \right|^{-1/2} \left| B \right|^{1/2} \left|  B+cACA^T \right|^{-1/2}. $$

Is this correct?

Comment: For sufficiently small $c$, your first (second) expression approximates $|cC|^{-1/2}$ ($|cC|^{1/2}$), so I suspect you have a sign error in at least one exponent.

Comment: Please show what you have tried to simplify the one or the other expression. You can square both expressions, then see if they are equal. Nota that $(\det A)^{-1}=\det(A^{-1}$. It may be useful to replace $B^{-1}$ by $D^2$ or so...

Comment: This is not correct, Take the case $n = k  =1$.

Comment: I made a mathematical typo in my expression and i just made a correction now. I cannot remember where I have seen it but the equivalent form is given and I'm wondering how the first expression reached to this equivalent form.

Comment: In general one cannot simplify the determinant of a sum of matrices. Do you have any reason to suspect that this particular determinant-of-a-sum can be simplified?

Comment: The way I worded my problem may not be clear due to my lacking in English. It is not necessary for me to simplify this determinant greatly. I'm focusing on theoretical problem and I'm looking for an alternative/equivalent form of this determinant to make my computation easier since the first expression is possibly infeasible to solve in my computations theoretically.
I'm just checking if the given equivalent form is correct with support of some Matrix Algebra definitions/properties and not some make-up expression.